# Java calling Oracle SQL Stored Procedure with varchar IN/OUT. ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I've a stored procedure with varchar in and out that is called by java

**Stored Procedure** SP_Materials

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_Materials(
   ITEM_ID IN VARCHAR2,
   ITEM_DESC OUT VARCHAR2
)AS
BEGIN
     IF (ITEM_ID = '01') THEN
        ITEM_DESC := 'Hammer';
     END IF;
     IF(ITEM_ID = '02') THEN
        ITEM_DESC := 'Nail';
     END IF;
END SP_Materials;
```

Here's what I've tried in JAVA

```
    try {
        CallableStatement callableStatementReturn = null;
        String callableStatement = "{call SP_Materials(?,?)}";
        Connection dbConn =
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.20.30.40:1111:SID1", "user", "pass");
        callableStatementReturn = dbConn.prepareCall(callableStatement);
        callableStatementReturn.setString(1, "01");
        callableStatementReturn.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR,1000);
        callableStatementReturn.executeQuery();

        System.out.println( callableStatementReturn.getCharacterStream(2).read());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error:
>   character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at "FUSION.SP_MATERIALS",
>   line 8 ORA-06512: at line 1
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)  at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:223)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:56)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:907)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1119)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeInternal(T4CCallableStatement.java:1300)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3822)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165)
>     at fusiondbconnectionpackage.TESTCLASS.main(TESTCLASS.java:71) Caused
>   by: Error : 6502, Position : 0, Sql = BEGIN SP_Materials(:1 ,:2 );
>   END;, OriginalSql = {call SP_Materials(?,?)}, Error Msg = ORA-06502:
>   PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
>   ORA-06512: at "FUSION.SP_MATERIALS", line 8 ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: Please try `callableStatementReturn.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);` without the length of 1000.

Comment: @hol same thing happened. that was what I initially tried the one without scale

Comment: Have you tried adding a line `callableStatementReturn.setString(2, "Some text");`? It is possible that you have to initialize all parameters regardless if the are declared only as out or not...